# fixed positioned div should become visible at top header location after user scroll reach form below in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my program includes a hidden fixed positioned div which should become               visible at top header location when user scrolls reached a form which is between the page and after that fixed positioned div should remain at top header location till the page end.error in my code:- fixed div is always visible. looking for the solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.now-show').hide(); 
  if ($('.now').is(":visible") == true) { 
    $('.now-show').show();  
  }
});
```

```html
<div style="height:50px;background:green;width:100%;">header</div>
<div style="padding-bottom:2000px;">form is below</div>


<div style="background:orange;height:50px;">
  <form>
    I am form
    <input type="" size="0" style="border:none;border-bottom:1px solid white;background:orange;" placeholder="email" >
    <input type="" size="0" style="border:none;border-bottom:1px solid white;background:orange;" placeholder="phone" >
    <input type="" size="0" style="border:none;border-bottom:1px solid white;background:orange;" placeholder="name" >
  </form>
</div>

<div class="now" style="margin-top:150px;">
  NOW fixed positioned div should become visible at top header position
</div>
<div class="now-show" style="position:fixed;background:black;height:50px;top:0;bottom:0;color:white;width:100%;">
  i will behave as sticky fixed position div at top header when you reach the form below<br><br><br>
</div>
<div style="padding-top:2000px;">sticky div is still there at top</div>
```

Comment: You didn't add the jQuery in your jsFiddle.

Comment: Swati, can you kindly check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add up classes on scrolling down and remove the class on scrolling up

```
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
} else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    }
}
```

[demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this condition:

```
$(".now").offset().top == $(window).scrollTop()
```

And you have the **working snippet** here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.now-show').hide(); 
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(".now").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop())
      $('.now-show').show();
    else
      $('.now-show').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:50px;background:green;width:100%;">header</div>
<div style="padding-bottom:2000px;">form is below</div>


<div style="background:orange;height:50px;">
  <form>
    I am form
    <input type="" size="0" style="border:none;border-bottom:1px solid white;background:orange;" placeholder="email" >
    <input type="" size="0" style="border:none;border-bottom:1px solid white;background:orange;" placeholder="phone" >
    <input type="" size="0" style="border:none;border-bottom:1px solid white;background:orange;" placeholder="name" >
  </form>
</div>

<div class="now" style="margin-top:150px;">
  NOW fixed positioned div should become visible at top header position
</div>
<div class="now-show" style="position:fixed;background:black;height:50px;top:0;bottom:0;color:white;width:100%;">
  i will behave as sticky fixed position div at top header when you reach the form below<br><br><br>
</div>
<div style="padding-top:2000px;">sticky div is still there at top</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `:visible` [selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/): that isn't right, as your form isn't hidden, but just placed lower on the page.

You need to use `scroll` [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) with a condition, whether you your form is above the bottom edge of the window.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NeoSelcev/8c3vkrd1/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > $('form').offset().top) {
            $('.hiddenHeader').show();
        } else {
            $('.hiddenHeader').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div style="height: 50px; background: green; width: 100%;">header</div>
    <div class="hiddenHeader" style="display: none; height: 50px;  position: fixed; background: black; top: 0; color: white; width:100%; overflow: hidden;">i will behave as sticky fixed position div at top header when you reach the form below</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed porta risus quam, vel pretium lectus auctor ullamcorper. Suspendisse auctor leo nec orci semper commodo. Vestibulum semper erat et efficitur bibendum. In nulla diam, luctus quis magna et, gravida iaculis ligula. Integer nec commodo arcu. Fusce maximus libero vitae diam egestas, id tempus sem suscipit. Suspendisse dictum lectus metus, ac feugiat velit porttitor quis. Nulla non ultrices nulla. Pellentesque porta nibh sed facilisis laoreet.</p>
    <p>Aliquam sit amet euismod orci, sit amet porttitor ligula. Nunc pulvinar laoreet imperdiet. Mauris condimentum sagittis diam eget bibendum. Sed vestibulum ipsum sit amet enim faucibus, eget aliquet eros sollicitudin. Praesent at tellus et leo viverra volutpat. Praesent suscipit risus sed nisl maximus maximus. Fusce lacinia feugiat ipsum sed ornare. Nullam vestibulum mauris quis est molestie, vitae porta ligula placerat. Donec auctor sed ante ac ornare. Duis non lacus accumsan, pharetra dui non, bibendum quam. Nunc volutpat sollicitudin odio id tristique. Cras nec aliquet ipsum. Etiam gravida mauris vel laoreet hendrerit. Fusce at sapien tempus, faucibus purus non, placerat justo. Maecenas vitae cursus lectus.</p>
    <p>Suspendisse euismod, ipsum sed hendrerit convallis, ligula elit semper velit, sed malesuada mauris dui eu ipsum. Ut volutpat massa ut elit viverra lacinia. Sed consectetur enim laoreet blandit convallis. Donec feugiat vitae ex at hendrerit. Vestibulum auctor nulla blandit turpis congue vulputate. Ut condimentum egestas purus a ultrices. Sed tortor tortor, convallis in risus ut, porttitor elementum diam. Praesent eu semper augue. Vestibulum dignissim mi felis, vitae eleifend arcu sollicitudin eu.</p>
    <p>Praesent ac nibh imperdiet, convallis magna vitae, eleifend orci. Donec malesuada quam quis maximus eleifend. Vestibulum euismod, elit id mattis scelerisque, dolor tellus eleifend eros, in convallis felis est sit amet erat. Donec consequat libero vel ipsum imperdiet, finibus pharetra urna sagittis. Etiam pellentesque quam vitae mi scelerisque, eu feugiat urna finibus. Aenean id blandit magna. Duis vehicula, ante sed malesuada efficitur, neque eros pretium felis, eu ultricies mauris mi sed ante. Suspendisse et dolor massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis sed vulputate velit, quis condimentum magna. Aenean consectetur tincidunt lobortis. Aenean malesuada elementum nisl non sollicitudin. Morbi ullamcorper a dolor vel dapibus.</p>
    <p>Mauris vel ligula id mauris imperdiet euismod sit amet ac sapien. Donec eget tempus ligula. Vestibulum ut nisl volutpat, vulputate arcu nec, elementum nulla. Mauris commodo interdum velit in vulputate. Ut faucibus condimentum posuere. Sed porta id ex non pretium. Aenean est dui, feugiat at leo in, finibus elementum ante. Suspendisse non condimentum lectus. Suspendisse potenti. Ut at ex blandit risus aliquet elementum aliquam vel nibh. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent aliquam est vitae odio euismod feugiat. Curabitur gravida eget arcu id interdum.</p>
    <form style="background :orange; height: 50px;">I am form</form>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed porta risus quam, vel pretium lectus auctor ullamcorper. Suspendisse auctor leo nec orci semper commodo. Vestibulum semper erat et efficitur bibendum. In nulla diam, luctus quis magna et, gravida iaculis ligula. Integer nec commodo arcu. Fusce maximus libero vitae diam egestas, id tempus sem suscipit. Suspendisse dictum lectus metus, ac feugiat velit porttitor quis. Nulla non ultrices nulla. Pellentesque porta nibh sed facilisis laoreet.</p>
    <p>Aliquam sit amet euismod orci, sit amet porttitor ligula. Nunc pulvinar laoreet imperdiet. Mauris condimentum sagittis diam eget bibendum. Sed vestibulum ipsum sit amet enim faucibus, eget aliquet eros sollicitudin. Praesent at tellus et leo viverra volutpat. Praesent suscipit risus sed nisl maximus maximus. Fusce lacinia feugiat ipsum sed ornare. Nullam vestibulum mauris quis est molestie, vitae porta ligula placerat. Donec auctor sed ante ac ornare. Duis non lacus accumsan, pharetra dui non, bibendum quam. Nunc volutpat sollicitudin odio id tristique. Cras nec aliquet ipsum. Etiam gravida mauris vel laoreet hendrerit. Fusce at sapien tempus, faucibus purus non, placerat justo. Maecenas vitae cursus lectus.</p>
    <p>Suspendisse euismod, ipsum sed hendrerit convallis, ligula elit semper velit, sed malesuada mauris dui eu ipsum. Ut volutpat massa ut elit viverra lacinia. Sed consectetur enim laoreet blandit convallis. Donec feugiat vitae ex at hendrerit. Vestibulum auctor nulla blandit turpis congue vulputate. Ut condimentum egestas purus a ultrices. Sed tortor tortor, convallis in risus ut, porttitor elementum diam. Praesent eu semper augue. Vestibulum dignissim mi felis, vitae eleifend arcu sollicitudin eu.</p>
    <p>Praesent ac nibh imperdiet, convallis magna vitae, eleifend orci. Donec malesuada quam quis maximus eleifend. Vestibulum euismod, elit id mattis scelerisque, dolor tellus eleifend eros, in convallis felis est sit amet erat. Donec consequat libero vel ipsum imperdiet, finibus pharetra urna sagittis. Etiam pellentesque quam vitae mi scelerisque, eu feugiat urna finibus. Aenean id blandit magna. Duis vehicula, ante sed malesuada efficitur, neque eros pretium felis, eu ultricies mauris mi sed ante. Suspendisse et dolor massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis sed vulputate velit, quis condimentum magna. Aenean consectetur tincidunt lobortis. Aenean malesuada elementum nisl non sollicitudin. Morbi ullamcorper a dolor vel dapibus.</p>
    <p>Mauris vel ligula id mauris imperdiet euismod sit amet ac sapien. Donec eget tempus ligula. Vestibulum ut nisl volutpat, vulputate arcu nec, elementum nulla. Mauris commodo interdum velit in vulputate. Ut faucibus condimentum posuere. Sed porta id ex non pretium. Aenean est dui, feugiat at leo in, finibus elementum ante. Suspendisse non condimentum lectus. Suspendisse potenti. Ut at ex blandit risus aliquet elementum aliquam vel nibh. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent aliquam est vitae odio euismod feugiat. Curabitur gravida eget arcu id interdum.</p>
</body>
```

*** This is a basic example. If you want, you could add animations and transitions.